# "my react program doesn't render anything"

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

all my files are in the same folder,and here are my codes

index.js

```
import { keyboard, input_area } from "./ui.js";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
function main() {
    return (<div>
        <input_area />
        <keyboard />
    </div>)
}
const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("main"));
root.render(<div><main /></div>);
```

ui.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./style.css";
function input_area() {
    return (<textarea></textarea>);
}
function keyboard() {
    return (<div>
        <div className="center">
            <button>1</button><button>2</button><button>3</button><br></br>
            <button>4</button><button>5</button><button>6</button><br></br>
            <button>7</button><button>8</button><button>9</button><br></br>
        </div>
        <button className="center">submit</button>
    </div>);
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>CALC</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.0/react.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
    <div id="main"></div>
    <script type="module text/babel" src="./index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

i am tring to display a textarea and some buttons.but when i start my website with "npx http-server",it's blank.

edit 1

I edit my code and now it throws "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'" in index.js. Looks like babel doesn't work properly.How to fix it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>CALC</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div id="main"></div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src=" ./index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

```
// index.js
import { Keyboard, Inputarea } from "./ui.js";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
function Main() {
    return (<div>
        <Inputarea />
        <Keyboard />
    </div>);
}
const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("main"));
root.render(<Main />);
```

Comment: An enumerable number of things could be wrong. Is using create react app an option for you? It's an out-of-the-box preconfigured react boilerplate. No mess no fuss

Answer (score 0):

React component names should be capitalized. In your index.js and ui.js, you've named your components input_area and keyboard. These should be InputArea and Keyboard, respectively. This is crucial because React treats components starting with lowercase letters as DOM tags.

```js
// ui.js
function InputArea() {
    return (<textarea></textarea>);
}

function Keyboard() {
    return (/* ... */);
}
```

Correct Component Export and Import:
You should export your components from ui.js and import them correctly in index.js.

```js
// ui.js
export { InputArea, Keyboard };

// index.js
import { InputArea, Keyboard } from "./ui.js";
```

Fix Main Component:
In index.js, your main function is not a valid React component. It should be renamed to Main and returned as a component.

```js
function Main() {
    return (
        <div>
            <InputArea />
            <Keyboard />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Rendering Main Component:
In your root.render call,  should be .

```js
root.render(<Main />);
```

Ensure Babel Transpilation:
Ensure that Babel is correctly set up to transpile JSX. Your script tag in index.html has a typo in the type attribute. It should be type="module" and type="text/babel" separately, not combined.

```js
<script type="module" src="./index.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel"></script>
```

Version of React:
You are using an older version of React (15.0.0) which does not support the createRoot API. Either update React and ReactDOM to version 18 or above, or use the older ReactDOM.render() method.

If updating, your index.html should include:

```js
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

If not updating, use:

```js
// index.js
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.getElementById('main'));
```

To fix your React application, ensure that your components are properly named and exported, import them correctly in index.js, use the correct version of React that supports createRoot, and ensure that Babel is correctly set up for JSX transpilation. After making these adjustments, your application should render the textarea and buttons as intended.

Comment: I edit my code and new error occurs.How can I make babel work properly?